# Java: Read xml file with dynamicaly added elements without using QName

Tags: java, xml

I have a xml file, contains tags which are dynamically generated as below,

```
<ABC>
    <XYZ>
        <PQR DURI="http://try.org/claims">
            <LMN>
                <URI>http://yyyy/givenname</ClaimURI>
                <DName>First Name</DisplayName>
                <FoundationName>givenName</FoundationName>
                <Description>First Name</Description>
                <Required />
                <DisplayOrder>1</DisplayOrder>
                <SuppDefault />
            </LMN>
            <LMN>
                <CURI>http://kkkk/nickname</ClaimURI>
                <DisplayN>Nick Name</DisplayName>
                <AttributeID>nickName</AttributeID>
                <SDA>23edded<SDA>
                <Description>Nick Name</Description>
                <Required />
                <DisplayOrder>2</DisplayOrder>
                <TransitNumber>89393</TransitNumber>
            </LMN>
         </PQR>
     </XYZ>
</ABC>
```

I want read the above xml format and added them to a `Map<String,String>` as key/value pair, tag name and value respectivly. I dont know the tag names in-between `<LMN>` tags, because those are adding dynamically. Is there possible way of doing that.

I have tried using following code,

```
  Root = element.getFirstChildWithName(new QName(XYZ)
        OMElement IteratorOne = Root.getChildrenWithLocalName(PQR)
        Iterator<OMElement> IteratorTwo = dialect.getChildrenWithLocalName(LMN);
        while (IteratorTwo.hasNext()) {
            Element = IteratorTwo.next();
            Iterator iterator = Element.getChildren();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                iterator.next();
            }
        }
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: You want to store all LMN values into singlemap or a map for each LMN

Answer (score 0):

I had ones done this for one of a piece of work. I had used a dom parser to do that. Here is a the code excerpt that i reworked a bit to fit your use. I am assuming in the code that myString contains your XML text. If you have a stream at your disposal you can directly use it in dBuilder.

```
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes());

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("LMN");

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            convertNodeToMap(nNode, map);
        }
```

This is the code for convertNodeToMap

```
public static void convertNodeToMap(Node node, Map<String, String> map) {
    if (node != null) {
        if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
            NodeList list = node.getChildNodes();
            for (int count = 0; count < list.getLength(); count++) {
                map.put(list.item(count).getNodeName(), list.item(count).getTextContent());
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

If the input document size is comparatively bigger in size you must be aware that DOM parsing can get slow.